# How can I get mouse focus on Windows PCs when using modal Swing?

Tags: java, windows, swing, modal-dialog, focus

I need to drag windows that do not have keyboard focus on Windows 10 computers.  Swing functions on my PC deny "mouse focus" on all windows in the same java application; they are locked out of being moved or uncovered for viewing.

The latest Swing dialog window controls the show; any other window that is needed for viewing (to help on answering the dialog) is unavailable when it is covered by another application window. On the Mac/OS X, mouse focus is not a problem; all windows seem to have it.

Is there a way to get this "mouse focus" on the PC when using the convenient modal Swing functions?

The 3 windows at issue in my application are:

1. Dialog: The latest Swing dialog hording all the mouse focus
2. Blocker: A JFrame or JDialog window that may or may not be an ancestor of Dialog but it is a big enough window to block view of Blockee
3. Blockee: The one that has information needed to answer the Dialog.
   Only Dialog can be dragged on Windows 10 in this situation.
   Is moving the information needed into the Dialog the only answer?
   Are there windows 10 settings that can make it perform more sensibly?
   I tried using different threads for Blockee and Blocker to no avail.

Comment: I have never had a problem dragging a modal JDialog. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Yes, when you open a modal JDialog, the underlying JFrame can not be moved on Windows 10.  Either make your JDialog smaller so it can be moved out of the way, or copy the information from the JFrame to the JDialog so the user doesn't have to refer back to the JFrame.

Comment: Unfortunately what Mr. Le Blanc is saying looks correct.  I edited my question to inspire better alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fairly easy workaround for many cases: Identify the Blocker window and then take away its focusability (perhaps temporarily) when it might be a blocker and is no longer needed.

```
java.awt.Frame blocker = this; // or <parent> <grandparent>, etc.
blocker.setFocusable(false);
```

This does not make the Blocker or Blockee window moveable but it eliminates the problem by preventing the blocking. Maybe some day there will be a better solution for this in Windows 10.